# Convert multiple selected range into number

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data of more than 70,000 rows and 5 or more columns which have numbers in TEXT format and to convert those numbers i use the following code:

```
'LastRow
  vLastRow= Cells(Rows.Count, ActiveCell.Column).End(xlUP).row

'Select
  Range(Cells(Selection.row, ActiveCell.column),Cells(vLastRow, ActiveCell.column).Select
       With Selection
            .NumberFormat="#,##0.00_);(#,##0.00)"
            .value=.value
            .HorizontalAlignment=xlRight
       End With
Active.Select
```

When i select the 1 column it worked fine, but when i select multiple columns by pressing **Ctrl** and click to specific columns then code stop working.

Also, I can't specific the cell and columns because these are not static.

Comment: Because `ActiveCell.column` corresponds to only one column.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is on the right track. There are a few ways you could achieve this with minimal modification.

### Use an `InputBox` to prompt for the range to be reformatted.

In this solution, I have set the `Default Value` for the input box as the address for the Selected cells which means you could select the range you want to reformat (as you are attempting to do) and then trigger your code to have the selected range auto populate:

```
Sub ConvertDynamicRangeToNumber()
Dim UserRange As String

UserRange = InputBox("Enter the start and end of your range (e.g. A1:C10):", "Enter your range", Selection.Address(False, False))

With Sheet1.Range(UserRange)
    .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_);(#,##0.00)"
    .Value = .Value
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
End With

End Sub
```

---

### Use the selected range

If you'd prefer to skip the `InputBox` and just base it on the selected cells, you could just `Set UserRange = Selection.Address` but that means **if incorrect cells are selected and you run your code, there is no undo and you might end up with more work then you started with!**

To avoid this add a `MsgBox` to allow an abort in case a mistake was made.

```
Sub ConvertDynamicRangeToNumber1()
Dim UserRange As String
Dim Confirmation As String

UserRange = Selection.Address(False, False)

Confirmation = MsgBox("You have selected the range " & UserRange & " ." & vbNewLine & _
vbNewLine & "Is this correct?", vbYesNo + vbCritical, "Are you sure?")

If Confirmation = vbYes Then
    With Sheet1.Range(UserRange)
        .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00_);(#,##0.00)"
        .Value = .Value
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    End With
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```